# Why doesn't my screen turn off after 30 seconds?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, settings, screen

Two days back I had to do a factory reset on my android (v2.3.6). After that, I noticed that my phone display won't turn off after 30 secs idle time, even though the settings has been done appropriately. After 30 secs, the brightness decreases, but the screen won't turn off. Is there any other setting which needs to be changed here?

Comment: Could it be some app prevents the display from being (automatically) turned off? You can check the permissions of installed apps to check for those having the appropriate permission. You could use e.g. [AppBrain Ad Detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.detector) for this (it also scans the permissions of installed apps).

Comment: Try the wakelock detector app.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the wakelock detector app which will tell you the application which is restricting the phone from going to sleep and lock mode.

Unfortunately it did not work for me since my kitkat version required the ROOT permission.

I fixed it by going to "Settings > Apps > Running tab". I closed all suspicious application in "Cached" and "running' mode.

It was one of my recent ip-camera phone app or the Alexa app which was restricting the phone going to auto sleep after 15 seconds and then to lock state.

The phone is working fine now after closing those 2 apps, I can run them when required.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the setting that keeps Screen On while Charging got Switched On. Try switching it off.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it turned out that one of my apps had permissions to my camera and was accessing it all the time. Turning off that permission resolved it.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, I cleared my apps, by holding the home button and making them all disappear and it worked.  Not sure what exactly the problem was :P